# Issue with jquery buttonset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

"cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'widget' "

On the first time load the buttonset() works fine. On the second load the entire UI freezes and I get this exception;

After researching and googling for sometime I have listed few jquery tickets which are
[wontfix](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8761), [Duplicate](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9570) ,[patcheswelcome](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9386) , [link1](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/uncaught-error-cannot-call-methods-on-button-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-call-method-widget), [link2](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-1-8-5-issue-with-buttonset-can-only-be-called-once-on-a-page)

My issues is similar to link2 but have only one buttonset() declared;
jQuery Version: 2.0.2 and jQueryUI version: 1.10.3

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SsneE/1/ I have just created a replica to generate the error. Apart from that even if I given unique name to radio groups its still not working!